# Redis with wsl2 podman - connection refused

Tags: redis, wsl-2, podman

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 within WSL2 on Windows 10.

I installed podman.

```
>podman -v
 podman version 3.
```

I tried starting a container with

```
podman run --name some-redis -d -p 6379:6379 redis
```

The container is starting. No errors in the log.

If I tried

```
redis-cli
```

From Ubuntu it's working.

From dos/powershell it is not working

```
rdcli -h localhost
localhost:6379> (error) Redis connection to localhost:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
```

And also it is not working with my SpringBoot application.

I'm also using a portainer container with port mapping 9000:9000 and I can access it from ubuntu, dos, powershell.

So what's the problem with redis.  Is it coming from redis or from wsl2/podman ?

What can I do.

ps : The same container on the same machine with docker desktop was working fine.

Comment: Just guessing. Maybe related to this issue?: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/12701#issuecomment-1000999833

Comment: Perhaps .... But I found that not using rootless is working.  But only the first time (at creation).  After rebooting and starting the container it is not working anymore.  The only solution : delete the container and recreate it.  Still don't know why ?

Answer (score 4):

You probably run into this WSL2 issue: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4851

Solution:

- option 1: use `[::1]:6379` instead of `localhost:6379` from Windows side
- option 2: use `-p 127.0.0.1:6379:6379` instead of `-p 6379:6379` with `podman run`.

Comment: Thanks guys, your answer saved my life, lol